# In-depth resources

Tags: reference-request, education, online-resources

How to learn mathematical topics in-depth? For instance, if you want to learn about *Symmetry*, you would use Google, you'll get results. Unfortunately, what you'll find is tutorials for beginners. But if you want to learn it in-depth? How I am supposed to search for resources? Do I have to check each book in my college's library?

**NOTE**: Symmetry is just an example. The topic could be anything.

Comment: Pick a topic you want to know about, try to figure out as much as you can on your own within reason. Then search for what doesn't make sense, and if you can't find anything online that really suits your needs, come to a place like here and ask away! Rinse and repeat. As you ask questions, you will realize what topics your interests are related to, and from there can just pick up some free online textbook, etc... to read. Once you get really good, wikipedia, arxiv, and other libraries holding higher level content become easy for you to use and speed up the "find what I 'm looking for" process.

Comment: Look up BookZZ if you want a resource for your textbooks.